# Keyboard Interrupt in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am writing a python program that requires a keyboard interrupt which I am unable to generate as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does not work as per requirement and I am writing it in a Jupyter Notebook. I have tried it, but interrupting kernel does not seem to solve my problem.